# failing to move data from one controller to another in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search controller and a  Category  controller and a shared properties factory. In my Category controller i set a sharedproperties.property but i fail to retrieve the data in Search controller its seems to be empty data here is my code

```
.factory('sharedProperties', function () {
        var property = '';

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;
            }
        };
 })


.controller("SearchCtrl",['config','sharedproperties',function(config,sharedproperties)
{

$scope.search_subCategory_businesses= function()
        {
            $scope.bus_es = sharedProperties.getProperty();
            console.log("sharedProperty hahahaah is",sharedProperties.getProperty()); //logs empty instead of data

            angular.forEach($scope.bus_es,function(value,key)
                        {
                            $scope.business = value;

                            if($scope.business.logo == '' || $scope.business.logo==null)
                            {
                                $scope.business.logo=config.BaseImageURL+"uploads/defbanner.png"
                            }else
                            {
                                $scope.business.logo=config.BaseImageURL+$scope.business.logo;
                            }
                            this.push($scope.business);

                        },$scope.businesses);

        };

        //$scope.search_resultsFunction();
        $scope.search_subCategory_businesses();


}])



.controller("CategoryCtrl",['config','sharedproperties',function(config,sharedproperties)
{

$scope.getBusinesses=function(sub_category_id)
    {
           $.get($scope.BaseURL+"classes/util.php?sub_category_id="+sub_category_id+"&transaction=get_businesses",function(results){

                alert("results are"+JSON.parse(results));
                $scope.bus_es =JSON.parse(results);
                sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.bus_es);//successfully sets property

                console.log("sharedProperty is",sharedProperties.getProperty());
                window.location.href=BaseURL+"search.php";
        });


    }

}])
```

Comment: it doesn't look like `sharedProperties` is included in your controllers.

Comment: You need to inject the service into your controllers. Now you are injecting only 'config'?

Comment: well i had just forgot when posting the question but they are injected

Comment: Category c0ontroller successfully updates the property

Comment: my problem is in search controller when i want to pick the data it logs that sharedproperties.getProperty() is empty

Comment: Any errors in the log ? 

Did you try using $http. $http.get($scope.BaseURL+"classes/util.php?sub_category_id="+sub_category_id+"&transaction=get_businesses").then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing jQuery callbacks and Angular Promises. You should call the BackEnd via $http and use promises. Documentation for $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```html
.factory('sharedProperties', function () {
        var property = '';

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;
            }
        };
 })


.controller("SearchCtrl",['config','sharedproperties',function(config,sharedproperties)
{

$scope.search_subCategory_businesses= function()
        {
            $scope.bus_es = sharedProperties.getProperty();
            console.log("sharedProperty hahahaah is",sharedProperties.getProperty()); //logs empty instead of data

            angular.forEach($scope.bus_es,function(value,key)
                        {
                            $scope.business = value;

                            if($scope.business.logo == '' || $scope.business.logo==null)
                            {
                                $scope.business.logo=config.BaseImageURL+"uploads/defbanner.png"
                            }else
                            {
                                $scope.business.logo=config.BaseImageURL+$scope.business.logo;
                            }
                            this.push($scope.business);

                        },$scope.businesses);

        };

        //$scope.search_resultsFunction();
        $scope.search_subCategory_businesses();


}])



.controller("CategoryCtrl",['$http','config','sharedproperties',function($http,config,sharedproperties)
{

$scope.getBusinesses=function(sub_category_id)
    {
           $http.get($scope.BaseURL+"classes/util.php?sub_category_id="+sub_category_id+"&transaction=get_businesses").then(function(results){

                alert("results are"+JSON.parse(results));
                $scope.bus_es =JSON.parse(results);
                sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.bus_es);//successfully sets property

                console.log("sharedProperty is",sharedProperties.getProperty());
                window.location.href=BaseURL+"search.php";
        });


    }

}])
```

Even better is doing those http-calls in a service that is responsible for your communication to the backend.

Comment: Well thank you @Kenneth but i noticed that my problem is that for me to update the search controller i need to first call a function yet in actual sence the search controller has already loaded so i load it before the property of the service has been set..So i still need help to go out of this trap

Comment: The easiest solution would be for you to create a plnkr with some test data, then i can see the logic and correct it.